# Number Theory excercise

Tags: number-theory

please I need your help with this problem

Let $p$, $q$ prime numbers, $ p<q$, $p$ divides $q-1$. Show that exist an integer $k$ such that $k \not\equiv 1$ mod $q$ and $k^p \equiv 1$   mod $q$.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you looked at small values of $p$ and $q$ where $p$ divides $q-1$ and tried to find $k$ with the desired properties? How about when $p=3$ and $q=7$? Do you already know Fermat’s Little Theorem, which says that for any integer $a$, $a^{q-1}\equiv1\mod q$?

Comment: (In Fermat’s Little Theorem, I left out the necessary requirement that $a$ not divisible by $q$.)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Fermat's Little Theorem and the Euler Fermat Theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Discrete Logarithm](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiscreteLogarithm.html) wrt some primitive root $g\pmod p$ on $\displaystyle k^p\equiv1\pmod q,$

$\displaystyle p\cdot$ind$_gk\equiv0\pmod{q-1}$

which is true for all integer $k$ as $p|(q-1)$